# Is closure is the way to avoid global variable?

Tags: function, functional-programming, closures, global-variables

I know that using global variable is not good practice and programmers should avoid it when possible.

```
func foo(a *A) func() *A {
    return func() *A {
        return a
    }
}
```

If I call `foo_closure` inside another function `bar` it would mean that output of `bar` will not depend on its input arguments and `bar` cannot be pure function.

Now I cannot see a difference between accessing `a *A` variable by closure or by global variable. In both cases they make an output unpredictable.
Can closure be considered an evil thing as global variable?

P.S 
Other functions can also call `foo_closure` and mutate its fields.

Comment: As long as you are not *mutating* your environment (which is necessary for pure functions), using variables from any scope is fine - be it the global or a closure scope. Make them constants with immutable values.

Comment: What is `foo_closure`, what is `bar`, and why do you think it can't be pure?

Comment: @Bergi making them global unnecessarily, though, litters the global namespace. and having them inside a closure makes the mutation safe(r)(ish) // more under control.

Comment: @WillNess Sure, the variable should be placed in a local scope/namespace/whatever to avoid collisions, but my point was that the scope doesn't matter: it's only important that the variable is not mutated.

Comment: right; without mutation everything is pure; if we must have mutation we better have it *under control*.

Answer (score 1):

The output is unpredictable with a global variable if "something else" besides your function `yourfunc` changes the global variable's value in between the calls to `yourfunc`.

But if the variable `var` is enclosed inside a closure and is accessible only to `yourfunc`, nothing else has access to it so can't change it so `yourfunc`'s output becomes entirely predictable by the arguments to `yourfunc` and by `yourfunc`'s actions (like, mutating the enclosed variable `var`, which can only be done from inside `yourfunc`).

Which increases safety and purity, which is the whole point to having closures in the first place.

The value of a function depends on its environment, comprised of its arguments, and the enclosed variables.

Another use of closures is when the enclosed environment is *shared* between *several* functions, so that only those functions can access and alter the enclosed variables' values.

Having variables global unnecessarily, litters the global name space and makes them liable for erroneous access.

Comment: If `yourfunc` mutates the variable it closes over, it becomes stateful and is no longer pure.

Comment: yes, and this impurity is under its exclusive control. Haskell has State too.

Comment: You might have restricted where the mutation can occur in your code (so that it's easier to reason about, especially in the absence of multithreading), but it's not "under control" as you don't restrict where the closure can be called in the application.

Comment: wherever `my_function` is called from, only the code inside `my_function` has access to the enclosed variable.